# Can OpenLayers2 render a completely custom font-face in a text or point symbolizer?

Tags: openlayers-2, rendering, font

I am trying to style a feature using a custom font.

Geoserver has an extension allowing external graphics in SLD to be defined by a font.  OpenLayers doesn't appear to support this particular Geoserver SLD extension.  Should OpenLayers.Format.SLD.v1_0_0_GeoServer do this? I did't see anything in that class to indicate it would.

If not, is there some other way to get open layers to load a true type font from an external resource?  I'm thinking something along the lines of CSS3 @font-face which would then make the font available when styles are created in the the many ways OL provides.

As a last resort, I could export all the glyphs in the font to SVG, but I would rather avoid that if possible.

**EDIT:**

Several OpenLayers examples involve client side feature styling:

- Vector Behavior Example
- Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) Example

Geoserver provides an SLD extension that allows the use of [TTF marks](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/pointsymbols.html#ttf-marks) to style data.  It's not clear to me if OpenLayers allows this or not.

For example, could OpenLayers consume an SLD with a point symbolizer like:

```
 <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>ttf://Webdings#0x0064</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:PropertyName>#0000ff</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#ff00ff</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </Mark>
          <Size> 45 </Size>
          <Rotation> 0 </Rotation>
        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```

which works fine in Geoserver.
If OpenLayers could do this, it would seem that either the font would have to be on a search path somehow.

Comment: Can you tell us what exactly you want to achieve? When you use SLD in Geoserver, Geoserver will use that SLD to create the map Image. Why do you need to access it in OpenLayers?

Comment: Not trying to style WMS.  I have an OL.Layer.Vector I want to style. I have been adding to OL.Renderer.symbol, but these symbols cannot be discontinuous - the entire symbol has to be a single polygon. I'm wondering if you can use a font glyph instead of a graphicName or externalGraphic in a style / styleMap.